# Custom Views in Multi-Tenant ASP.NET MVC Application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, scalability

I want to start a new web project where the user can create and share content, which is displayed on a portal site and on a custom site for each user. This custom sites can be configured, for example you can choose a design and you can also override the templates.

I want to use ASP.NET MVC with Razor, because I have a alot of experience with C#, .NET and ASP.NET.t.

I see the following requirements:
1. You need very fast access to the templates.
2. Changing the templates means a new assembly that is loaded and cannot be unloaded.
3. The system should be ready for hundreds of sites.

At the beginning I thought It would be a good idea to have only one site, but If I need multiple servers I have to clone the templates. I only see the option to run a custom instance for each site, but this means that making updates becomes hard. Any ideas? How would you solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You may take a look at [DotLiquid](http://dotliquidmarkup.org/) which is a templating engine you could use without giving too much power to your users (which is what would happen if you give them the possibility to use Razor).